# Why do I get response code 301 for every API request?

Tags: bigcommerce

I am trying to use BigCommerce's Playground but I always get response code as 301 with no product results.

I am working with BigCommerce for the first time and my client has his own domain name so the API path that I have is `https://my-domain-name/api/v2/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the BC developer portal playground, you need to use just the store URL. Full API path is not required.

I think if you remove the api/v2/ from the API path, it should work.